# Round to Nearest in IEEE 754

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

In IEEE 754 there is a "Round to Nearest" method of rounding floating point values.

But I do not understand one item in that definition:

> If the two nearest representable values are equally near, the one with
>   its least significant bit zero is chosen

What is "least significant bit zero is chosen"

Comment: `012345678`, in this case the 8 is the least significant bit. The bit (or number) that changes the number the least. Add one to `#8` and you will only increment the number. Add one to `#0` and you will increase it by `10000000`. Now, bits are stored `0001 0010`, the previous was just an example. Did that do it for you?

Comment: So, if we have two neibour single-precision floating-point numbers with mantissa written in binary form: 1.00000000000000000000001 and 1.00000000000000000000010 then the second number will be chosen as it contains zero on last 23d position?

Comment: That is how I understand it yes.

Comment: It is what is also called "[bankers' rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I understood the issue.
Single and Double precission numbers can be represented as 32 and 64 sequence of bits with the following way:

```
b bbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

b bbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Here b is zero or one.
First group corresponds to sign of a number.
Second group corresponds to exponent of a number and consist of 8 (single precission) and 11 (double precision) bits.
Third group corresponds to mantissa of a number and consist of 23 (single precission) and 52 (double precision) bits.

Hence, the `least significant bit` of a number is 23d bit of mantissa for single precission number and 52d bit of mantissa for double precission number. This is the rightmost bit of a number. If this bit is zero it will be chosen.

**Note:**
Even and odd numbers are defined only for integer values.
Hence, if rounding function rounds numbers only to integer values this rule degenerates to `round-to-even rule`

Thanks to everyone for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to play with the round-to-even rule is to round double-precision numbers written in [hexadecimal](http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/) to single-precision, for instance in the C99 or Java programming languages.

Single-precision has 23 explicit binary digits, so that the numbers 0x1.000000p0, 0x1.000002p0, 0x1.000004p0, … are single-precision numbers, but the numbers in-between aren't.

When a value is exactly in-between two consecutive single-precision floating-point numbers l and u, the binary expansions of l and u differ in the the 23 bit after the dot in the notation 1.bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb * 2<sup>exp</sup>. This is a simple consequence of l and u being consecutive.

The double-precision numbers 0x1.000001p0, 0x1.000003p0, 0x1.000005p0, … are exactly in-between two single-precision numbers are need to be rounded according to the “least significant bit zero” rule.

Example C99 program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int c, char *v[]) {
  double d = 0x1.000001p0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("double-precision:%.6a\n"
           "single-precision:%.6a\n\n",
           d, (float) d);
    d += 0x0.000002p0;
  }
}
```

Results illustrating how rounding goes to the single-precision value with a 0 as 23d binary digit after the dot:

```
double-precision:0x1.000001p+0
single-precision:0x1.000000p+0

double-precision:0x1.000003p+0
single-precision:0x1.000004p+0

double-precision:0x1.000005p+0
single-precision:0x1.000004p+0

double-precision:0x1.000007p+0
single-precision:0x1.000008p+0

double-precision:0x1.000009p+0
single-precision:0x1.000008p+0

double-precision:0x1.00000bp+0
single-precision:0x1.00000cp+0

double-precision:0x1.00000dp+0
single-precision:0x1.00000cp+0

double-precision:0x1.00000fp+0
single-precision:0x1.000010p+0

double-precision:0x1.000011p+0
single-precision:0x1.000010p+0

double-precision:0x1.000013p+0
single-precision:0x1.000014p+0
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that tie-breakers are resolved by rounding to even. It is also known as [Banker's rounding](https://wiki.c2.com/?BankersRounding). For example, 3.5 is rounded to 4.0, but 4.5 is rounded to 4.0. This also affects numbers  that are too large to be exactly represented. For example, in 32-bit floating point the integer 16777219 is rounded to 16777220.0 and not 16777218.0 because the latter's representation ends with a one.