IEEE floating-point rounding in C
I am having trouble to understand a specific IEEE double computation.  Take the following C99 program, that runs on a host with IEEE double (8 bytes, 11 bits biased exponent, 52 bits encoded mantissa):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>

// Expect IEEE double
int _a[sizeof (double) == 8 ? 1 : -1];

#define PP(X) printf (#X " = %d\n", X)

int main (void)
{
  // Print rounding modes.
  PP (FE_TONEAREST);
  PP (FE_UPWARD);
  PP (FE_DOWNWARD);
  PP (FE_TOWARDZERO);

  // What mode do we have?
  printf ("rounding mode = %d\n", fegetround());

  // Add a and b.
  double a = -0x1.638e38e38e38ep5;
  double b = -0x1.638e38e38e38ep6;
  __asm ("" : "+r" (a));
  __asm ("" : "+r" (b));
  printf ("a   = %a\n", a);
  printf ("b   = %a\n", b);
  printf ("a+b = %a\n", a + b);

  return 0;
}

Compile and run:
$ gcc rounding.c -lm && ./a.out
FE_TONEAREST = 0
FE_UPWARD = 2048
FE_DOWNWARD = 1024
FE_TOWARDZERO = 3072
rounding mode = 0
a   = -0x1.638e38e38e38ep+5
b   = -0x1.638e38e38e38ep+6
a+b = -0x1.0aaaaaaaaaaaap+7

My question is: Why the least significant nibble of the sum is a and not rounded to b as round-to-nearest is on?
In a IEEE double emulation with 56 bits for the decoded mantissa, the computation is like this:
# Printed the double values, same like on the host:
A   = -0x1.638e38e38e38ep5
B   = -0x1.638e38e38e38ep6
# Internal format with 56-bit mantissa. The digit after | indicates
# three extra bits compared to IEEE.
# 
A     = -0x1.638e38e38e38e|0, expo = 5
B     = -0x1.638e38e38e38e|0, expo = 6
A + B = -0x1.0aaaaaaaaaaaa|8, expo = 7

So when A + B gets packed as a double, then this would round to
(double) (A + B) = -0x1.0aaaaaaaaaaabp+7

No?

Relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448/rules-for-rounding-positive-and-negative-numbers

see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365468/does-c-standards-fe-tonearest-rounding-mode-guarantee-that-halfway-ties-are-rou: "... if the two nearest representable values are equally near, the one with its least significant bit zero shall be delivered"

I found this one, so maybe mine is a dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34386360/round-to-nearest-in-ieee-754

The output from setting a to a positive number, double a = 0x1.638e38e38e38ep5;, and printing it with printf ("a   = %a\n", a); does not show a negative number,a   = -0x1.638e38e38e38ep+5. Please edit the question so the code and the output match exactly.

As your extended-precision data shows, the exact result of the addition is 1.0AAAAAAAAAAAA816•27, where bold shows the part that will fit in an IEEE-754 double-precision number (binary64); the 8 digit is beyond what can be represented.
The two numbers representable in binary64 that immediately surround this number are 1.0AAAAAAAAAAAA16•27 and 1.0AAAAAAAAAAAB16•27. These are equally distant from 1.0AAAAAAAAAAAA816•27. For the round-to-nearest, ties-to-even method, IEEE 754 4.3.1 says “… if the two nearest floating-point numbers bracketing an unrepresentable infinitely precise result are equally near, the one with an even least significant digit shall be delivered…”
The least significant binary digits of the candidates are 0 and 1 (since the least significant hexadecimal digits are A, 1010, and B, 1011). 0 is even and 1 is odd, so 1.0AAAAAAAAAAAA16•27 is chosen.

What does "infinitely precise" mean? This cannot be achieved with, say transcendental functions except for a very few finitely many cases like cos(0)=1. For multiplication and addition it is always possible though.

@emacsdrivesmenuts: “Infinitely precise” mean the exact mathematical result. It is achievable mathematically. For example, π is an infinitely precise value for the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter. It cannot be represented with a finite number of decimal digits, but that is irrelevant. We can manipulate it mathematically and implement algorithms that determine whether it is closer to one decimal numeral than another and so on, and that suffices to implement floating-point arithmetic.
